# Rewrite click() method in Selenium 2 (python)

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, click

I'm using Seleniun 2 webdriver (python) to run auto tests on IE browser.
One of major bugs in IE webdriver is that click() method does not work in 100% of cases. It happens sometimes when IE browser cannot set/looses focus on element. So, there's a workaround i googled to solve the problem-  first the parent element must be clicked/selected. After that click() on the current element always works.
I would like to add my own method, named for ex. ieclick() that would do something like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id')
parentElement = element.find_element_by_xpath('..')
parentElement.click()
element.click()
```

Instead of writing all this code i would like to make:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('id').ieclick()
```

But i don't know how to implement this. I'm lost in Selenium modules code. I know that selenium class has click() method but i can't understand how can i rewrite it/add my own and make it useble for all this find_element_by_id, find_element_by_xpath etc.

Can someone help me to understand this implementation or maybe paste a link to some sort of explanation/example/lesson ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that an element would not receive a click is because :

- The element is disabled.
- The element is invisible (therefore, cannot interact with it)
- The element is not listening for any clicks (not binded)

My guess is that your "inconsistency issue" is coming form the third reason.

Consider the following:

```
<a href="dosomething">
  <span id="spanclick">Click me</span>
</a>
```

Doing `driver.find_element_by_id("spanclick").click()` would not work, because it's the `<a>` element that is receiving the click, not the `<span>`.

It's your responsibility as the test writer to determine which element is receiving the click.  My suggestion would be use debugging anytime you are in doubt.  I've actually had a scenario where an `<li>` was receiving the actions of the mouse, not the `<a>`.  By using Watch Expressions you are able to find what element is receiving the actions.

Comment: Well it could be the case, but the problem is that click() works ~80% on the same element. There actually is a problem, can't say whether IE or Selenium is it's source. Besides, if i'm using FF with FF webdriver click() method on the same element works 100% of cases. Elements are links and bottons.

Comment: oh really?  that's extremely odd.  if only IE adhered to standards,  but that's neither here nor there.  If this solution doesn't help, then it's gotta be a problem with IE.

Comment: here's some info about this problem:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1415

Comment: Also, y'know, [blog](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) [posts](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html).

Answer (score 0):

Seems i was exaggerating the difficulty. 
selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py 
Added code right after native click() method:

```
def ieclick(self):
    """2013-12-27. Surely clicks the element in IE."""
    parent = self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='..')
    parent._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
    try:
        self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
    except:
        pass
```